# "shutdown -m" from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, shutdown

I recently discovered that it is possible to remotely shutdown a Windows machine (from another Windows machine) using the command `shutdown -m \\computername`

I currently have an overly complicated system accomplishing this from a Raspberry Pi using Python scripts running on both the Pi and the PC. I was curious how exactly this -m switch works. I presume it sends a packet to the PC which it interprets as a shutdown command. Is there some way I could replicate this from my Pi?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.lylebackenroth.com/blog/2010/06/29/manage-windows-remotely-from-a-linux-command-line-interface/

To reboot the server or PC and force all apps to shutdown gracefully:

`net rpc shutdown -r -f -I 192.168.0.5 -U "mydomain\john"`

Replace 192.168.0.5 with the correct IP address of course. 'net' is part of SAMBA but since you're already working with Linux and Windows I assume this is already installed and configured.